# when onFailure will call - ${remoteFunction -Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

My code is this:

```
${remoteFunction(controller:'user', action:'clearCache', 
params:'\'&cacheUserId=\' + cacheUserId + \'&pageName=\' + pageName', 
onSuccess: 'onSuccess()', 
onFailure: 'onFailure()') };
```

in my controller action method

```
clearCache(){

  def status = getBusiness(); // this method returns boolean only.
  if(status==true){
  render "Success"}
  else render "Failure"
}
```

new it is calling onSuccess() javascript function always.

so I deleted else block then it not calling onFailue/onSuccess in case of status is false.

can i know when onFailure will call, how can i make it call in case of status is false.

Answer (score 2):

the method

```
onSuccess (optional) - The JavaScript function to call if successful
```

means that if your controller success (as in this code) than this method is called

```
onFailure (optional) - The JavaScript function to call if the call fails
```

means that if your controller fail (ERROR 404 in example) than this method is called

that's why onSuccess is always called in your code.

Solution i think you can pass to your onSuccess function data param:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(data,textStatus){
        alert(data)

        }

    </script>
```

In data you can find the rendered response. Regards

Comment: I tryed that but the javascript console sais _'data is not defined'_

Answer (score 2):

You should change your controller code to explicitly send the appropriate HTTP status code when something "exceptional" happens. The [`render`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) method allows this via the `status` attribute.

```
clearCache(){
    def status = getBusiness(); // this method returns boolean only.
    if(status==true){
        render "Success" // implicit status of 200
    }
    else render(status: 403, text: "Failure")
}
```

As its not clear what sort of failure is happening in this example, I'm not sure which status code to specify, so I've gone with 403 but you need to read the [status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and choose the best one for your circumstances.

As @alessandro said, the `onSuccess` is triggered by a 2XX HTTP status code and most other codes will trigger the `onFailure` callback.